# How to run a C++ simple code in microsoft visual c++ express

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to run a very **simple c++ code** in **microsoft visual c++** but I can't.

In my c++ book , they told me that I can do it but it requares some steps and I don't know how to do.

So , please tell me how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Check this out, basic C++ Win32 application build in Visual Studio

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx

Get used to using MSDN, it's very helpful for answering questions on programming for Windows in Visual Studio.  A lot of sample code, both for common tasks and API-specific.

Comment: +1, informative answer given the question was the programming equivalent of "My planets are not in alignment, pls tell me why."

Comment: It's a bit overwhelming to start off with, but comprehensive